# Ksoap2 webservices function

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

So I'm trying to call a ksoap2 webservices and get some data from it but I keep getting an error and no output. On the webservices there is a section called HelloWorld which is only for testing and it works, I'm getting the right output, but when I'm trying to acces data from this section and it doesn't work keep getting errors.

This is the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;    
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeActivity{

private String SOAP_ACTION = "http://microlise.com/TMC/FindConsignmentSummaries";
private String NAME_SPACE = "http://microlise.com/TMC";
private String METHOD_NAME = "FindConsignmentSummaries";
private String url = "https://ws2.microlise.com/canon_live_webservice/TMCWebService.asmx?WSDL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page);

    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        //request.addProperty("HelloWorld","");

        SoapObject filter = new SoapObject( NAME_SPACE,"consignmentFilter");
        filter.addProperty("ConsignmentReference","");
        filter.addProperty("OrderReference","");
        filter.addProperty("EarliestDeliveryDate","");
        filter.addProperty("LatestDeliveryDate","");
        filter.addProperty("SiteID","");
        filter.addProperty("SiteName","");


        request.addSoapObject(filter);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;
        String requestDump = httpTransportSE.requestDump;
        String responseDump = httpTransportSE.responseDump;
        try {

            List<HeaderProperty> headersProperty = new ArrayList<>();
            headersProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + android.util.Base64.encodeToString("username:pass".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)));    //org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("Technet:CEVA".getBytes())));
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headersProperty);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            Log.d("RESULT_IS", " " + response.toString());
            Log.d("DEBUG_RESULT", " " + requestDump + " /" + responseDump);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute () {

    }
}
}
```

And this is the xml:

```
POST /canon_live_webservice/TMCWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ws2.microlise.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"         
xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
    <FindConsignmentSummaries xmlns="http://microlise.com/TMC">
      <consignmentFilter>
        <ConsignmentReference 
xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</ConsignmentReference>
        <OrderReference 
xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</OrderReference>
        <EarliestDeliveryDate 
xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">dateTime</EarliestDeliveryDate>
    <LatestDeliveryDate xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">dateTime</LatestDeliveryDate>
    <SiteID xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</SiteID>
    <SiteName xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</SiteName>
    <SiteAddress xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</SiteAddress>
    <SitePostCode xmlns="http://microlise.com/webservices/TMC/">string</SitePostCode>
  </consignmentFilter>
</FindConsignmentSummaries>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

And this is the error I`m getting:

```
Code: soap:Sender, Reason: Server was unable to read request. ---
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:138)
 at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:304)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:276)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? Thank you guys